# Not retrieving database fields dynamically inside a div using php

Tags: php, html

```
<div id="thumbnail-slider" >
    <div class="inner" style="height:500px;">
        <?php
        $query = "select * from released_movies";
        $queryr = $con->query($query);
        while ($row = $queryr->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?> 
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="single.php"><img src="../AbaamAdmin/Released_Movies/<?php echo $row['rel_movies_pics']; ?>" width="900" height="500" class="thumb"> </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        <?php } ?>

    </div> <!-- .inner-->
</div> <!-- .thumbnail-slider-->
```

The query is retrieving only 1 picture than the complete pictures given in the database. But if I remove the div , the query is executing fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the styles applied.

Comment: I think its css/html issue, please view source for generated HTML. Because you said removing div make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting and ending `<ul>` in while loop.

Which in incorrect, you should start it before while loop and end if after while loop.

Corrected code:

```
<?php
$query = "select * from released_movies";
$queryr = $con->query ( $query );
?>
<ul>
<?php
while ( $row = $queryr->fetch_assoc () ) {
?>
    <li><a href="single.php">
    <img src="../AbaamAdmin/Released_Movies/<?php echo $row['rel_movies_pics'];?>"
            width="900" height="500" class="thumb"> </a></li>
<?php }?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="thumbnail-slider">
    <div class="inner" style="height:500px;">
        <?php
        $query="select * from released_movies";
        $queryr=$con->query($query);
        ?>
        <ul>
            <?php           
            while($row=$queryr->fetch_assoc())
            {
                ?>          
                <li>
                    <a href="single.php">
                        <img src="../AbaamAdmin/Released_Movies/<?php echo $row['rel_movies_pics'];?>" width="900" height="500" class="thumb"> 
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php 
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- .inner-->
</div> <!-- .thumbnail-slider
```